# Implementing collapsible tabbed pane in Bootstrap 3 and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qqu7jgx/) with full code example.

I'm trying to implement a fairly sophisticated widget in Bootstrap 3/jQuery and am struggling to even find the right approach to tackling it. I want to present my users with the following *collapsible* navigation menu:

- Fizz Stuff

  - Goto Mars
  - Eat Pizza
- Buzz Stuff

  - Edit Widget
  - Goto Moon
- Foo Stuff

Where, on page load, only the 3 top-level menu items (Fizz Stuff, Buzz Stuff and Foo Stuff) are visible to the user. Only if the user clicks on one of these menu items does it expand into any existing submenus. If they click the main menu again, if it was expanded it will collapse back to its original state. Any selected menu item (top-level or otherwise) will act as the current selected tab in a tabbed pane.

So, for example, on page load the user sees:

[image]

Then, if they click the `Buzz Stuff` menu item, they'll see two submenus: Edit Widget and Goto Moon. If they click Edit Widget, they'll see:

[image]

I also need nesting so that submenus can have submenus that have submenus, etc.; all with this expanding/collapsing and tabbed pane behavior.

My attempt to accomplish this has failed miserably. As you can see in the jsFiddle, my main problem is that all the `<div>` tags that comprise the content for each tab display on page load, and they display *below* the nav menu. Instead, the only time the content div for a menu should be visible is if that menu was just clicked/selected. As soon as another menu is selected, the content pane for that menu/tab should change.

For example, clicking:

```
<li><a href="#">Goto Mars</a></li>
```

Should only show us:

```
<div id="goto-mars-content">
    <h1>You are now on Mars.</h1>
</div>
```

So a few things:

1. Are "content `<div>`s" even the best way to handle this? Is there something more Bootstrappy, some other widget, such as a `<ul>`, etc.?
2. How do I get all the content to be invisible on page load, and to only load the content for the menu that was just selected?
3. Styling: how do I put a border around this entire widget (that is, both the left nav menu and tabbed pane content)?

Answer (score 1):

1. In HTML you need to be semantic. Usually for navigation you want to use the **nav** tag. For the right side content a **div** tag is fine.
2. To do this you want to use bootstraps [tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs). Bootstrap has a good article with code written here.
3. To put a border around something you would use CSS [border](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) declaration.

http://liveweave.com/3Sseg0

## Update

answer from comments
Here is a liveweave of your request.

Comment: Thanks @Wes Duff (+1) - regarding those Bootstrap tabs, I don't see how I can organize them vertically (stacked on top of each other) and make them expandable/collapsible, any ideas?

Comment: You will need to overwrite the existing bootstrap.css with your own css. Cascading wise...

Here is a liveweave example of what you are asking
http://liveweave.com/NyCUqQ

Comment: Thanks again @Wes Duff (+1 again) - I really appreciate that example, however I see that it doesn't seem to allow for the concept of expandable/collapsible submenus like in my jsFiddle. Any idea how I could add this into your example? Thanks again!

Comment: I looked into that. You will have to write some custom javascript. Bootstrap does not allow you to use one link to expand/collapse and to show a tab section. 
You will need to create an onlick event in your javascript and create handler to create the function you desire.

Comment: Thanks @Wes Duff (+1 again) - but think about it, I already have a working example of this in my jsFiddle. This was accomplished completely (100%) using Bootstrap styles...so I guess I just don't see why JS would be needed if Bootstrap already supports this kind of behavior our of the box. Thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4qqu7jgx/

This was the link for your fiddle. I can see the collapse working but the tab is not. 

From your picture it shows you want the link to display a tabbed section and perform an accordion drop down.

Comment: http://liveweave.com/3Sseg0

Here is an update to the liveweave.

I made the first element list item collapsible and two sub list items that open up tabs. The sub tabs manage the active state of the first list item and the first list item onClick manages the active state as well. 

Note** This could be cleaned up but it was a quick example